# Image slider in uitableview with SDWebImage

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I am creating an app for iOS in which i have to show an image slider in each cell of UITableView and images will load from internet using SDWenImage library.
I want to show image slider in every cell of tableview and for the image, we have a url. Now my problem is that how to download image from internet and display in the slider of uitableview cell.

Comment: How to fix what exactly?

Comment: I want to show image slider in every cell of tableview and for the image, we have a url. Now my problem is that how to download image from internet and display in the slider of uitableview cell.

Comment: did you solve your problem?